# Java: use stream to check if a set contains a specific string value

Tags: java, filter, lambda, set, java-stream

I am working on a program that parses a csv file containing a list of movies and data on them such as director name, duration, genres, title, rating, year of release, and IMDB score. The program contains a movie object which sets each of these data points to an attribute. as the majority of the movies have multiple genres(i.e. they can be action, adventure, and fantasy) the attribute "genres" has the data type Set.

I am trying to make multiple lists that identify movies by single genre values such as "adventure", but I cannot figure out how to use a stream to parse the genres set.
what I have tried is as follows:

```
movies.stream().filter((m)->{m.getGenres().contains("Action");}).sorted((m1,m2)-> {Double.compare(m2.getImdbScore(), m1.getImdbScore());}).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
The method filter(Predicate<? super Movie>) in the type Stream<Movie> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> m) -> {})
```

. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What error do you get? Please edit your question and add the full text of the error message.

Comment: @tgdavies edited to include error message.

Comment: Look at your code -- why is there a `.` after `filter`? What is `stream()filter` meant to do?

Comment: Looks like a type inference issue. You can probably fix it by changing `(m)` to `(Movie m)`, or the comparator to `Comparator.comparingDouble(Movie::getImdbScore)`. A [mcve] would help a lot.

Comment: Or maybe it's the use of block lambdas without a `return`.

Comment: @tgvavies that was a typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: @shmosel the part I am having trouble with is getting a specific genre attribute not the comparison.

Comment: I understand, but bad generics can have cascading effects. Most likely it's the bad lambda syntax, but it's hard to help without more specific information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using lambdas wrong.
Either you use the curly brackets with returning something or the short form without it.

Try the following:

```
movies.stream()
      .filter(m -> m.getGenres().contains("Action"))
      .sorted((m1, m2) -> Double.compare(m2.getImdbScore(), m1.getImdbScore()))
      .limit(10)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This was what it was. I feel incredibly silly now.

Comment: Two minor points here, but you can use: `.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Movie::getImdbScore))`, assuming the OP's dataclass is called "Movie". Also, from Java 16 onward you can just call `.toList()` on the stream directly instead of using a `.collect()`.